# Simplifying a Modular Arithmetic Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there a theorem or rule that makes this equivalent modular arithmetic equation in a form of:
$$f(x) = (a + b)(x \ \mathrm{mod}\ 2 )$$
into something like this:
$$f(x) = (ax \ \mathrm{mod}\ 2 ) + (bx \ \mathrm{mod}\ 2 )$$
which later can be simplify using distributive law.

Comment: No.  There are two uses for "mod" and this one won't work like you want.  Take $a=b=5$ and $x=1$.  The first line gives $f(1) = 10$.  The second line gives $f(1) = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your first statement says that 
$$f(x)=(a+b)(x+2p)=ax+bx+2pa+2pb$$ while the second states that 
$$f(x)=2m+ax+2n+bx$$
for some $p,m,n$ in $\mathbb{Z}.$

The equality will hold under very special conditions. Can you take it from here?